# Does Java's implementation of OCSP and CRL checking handle intermediate CAs?

Tags: tls, certificates, public-key-infrastructure

I've read that Java provides OCSP and CRL checking for CertPaths via:
Security.setProperty("ocsp.enable", "true");
System.setProperty("com.sun.security.enableCRLDP", "true");

Do these implementations check for the OCSP and CRL of intermediate CAs as well, or do they only check the leaf certificate?

Answer (score 4):

The source code seems to say yes. Get it from [there](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/); then look at the files in `jdk/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/certpath/`. In particular, `PKIXCertPathValidator.java` implements the validation mechanism. In the `doValidate()` method, classes which will do the OCSP or CRL checking will be instantiated as `OCSPChecker` or `CrlRevocationChecker`, and they will be applied at the end on all certificates in the path (this is done by a `PKIXMasterCertPathValidator` instance).

Without looking at the code, this behaviour could have been deduced from the [API documentation on java.security.cert.PKIXCertPathChecker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/security/cert/PKIXCertPathChecker.html): the `init()` method explains quite plainly that all certificates in the path will be fed to the checker instance.

Comment: PKIXCertPathChecker javadoc in Java8 is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/security/cert/PKIXCertPathChecker.html